# Thread-safe interaction with DataGridView's datasource

Tags: c#, collections, datagridview, concurrency, synchronization

Suppose a DataGridView has as DataSource a BindingList. Some background thread may both read and write from this list. Clearly this is problematic if the DataGridView modifies the list while the background thread is enumerating it (InvalidOperationException: collection was modified). 
I can think of 3 solutions:

1. Synchronize access to the list
2. Use .Invoke() to obtain a copy of the list and enumerate on that. After enumerating, use another .Invoke() to replace the datasource with the (possibly) modified collection
3. Use a thread-safe collection as a datasource.

I think 2. causes too much overhead and none of the available tread-safe collections are as flexible as List/BindingList. My preference is thus approach 1., which could work if I would put all list accesses in a `lock (list.SyncRoot) { ... }` block, but then I would need to convince the DataGridView to do as well. Is this possible?